# Json Encoding Issue

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, encode

For some reason when I submit the form it says Message:  json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given on this line of the controller and not sure why. Does anyone see what the issue is?

Controller

```
function forgot_password_submit() 
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        $this->kow_auth->output('There was a problem submitting the form! Please refresh the window and try again!', FALSE);
        return;
    }

    $user_data = $this->users->get_user_by_username($this->input->post('username'));
    if ($user_data === NULL) 
    {
        $this->kow_auth->output('User does not exist in the database!', FALSE);
        return;
    }

    $already_sent_password = (isset($user_data->new_password_key) && isset($user_data->new_password_requested));
    if ($already_sent_password) 
    {
        $this->kow_auth->output('Check your email for your temporary password!');
        return;
    }

    if (!strtotime($user_data->new_password_requested) <= (time() - 172800)) 
    {
        $this->kow_auth->output('You have to wait 2 days before a new temp password can be emailed!', FALSE);
    } 
    else 
    {
        if ($this->kow_auth->forgot_password($this->input->post('username'))) 
        {
            $this->kow_auth->send_email('forgot_password', 'KOW Manager Forgot Password Email', $user_data);
            $this->kow_auth->output('A temporary password has been emailed to you!');
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->kow_auth->output('A temporary password could not be created for you!', FALSE);
        }
    }
}
```

kow_auth library

```
/**
* Generate output message
*
* @param string
* @return object
*/
function output($message, $success = TRUE) 
{
    $status = $success ? array('succes' => 'yes') : array('error' => 'yes');
    echo json_encode($status, $message);
}
```

Comment: You should really echo the json in a view, this goes against the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, the second parameter to `json_encode` is supposed to be a bitmask of options, not a message. You can only encode one thing at a time, not a string *and* an array. Maybe you want something like `json_encode(array($status, $message))`?

Comment: Where its supposed to displace the message.

Comment: That's too vague. You cannot encode a message and a status this way using `json_encode`, period. What do you expect the output to be? Whatever happens to the message output is an entirely different topic.